# output varies from simulator to device

Tags: iphone, ipad, xib

i have some icons placed at a particular position in the .xib file and they are being seen exactly at the same place while seen in simulator.. But, when i put it on the device,the images seems to come too close to each other and they are looking crippled or overlapped ... is there anything i can do to solve this problem... ? Thank you

Comment: Are your image files saved with 72 dpi? I have seen Interface Builder occasionally having problems with files that do not have 72 dpi (even though this value is almost meaningless for pixel-based display).

Comment: Hi ole.. this seems interesting.... i never knew about this issue.. can u tell me some more about this please... and how to check the pixels of our image?

Comment: Open the images in Preview.app, choose Tools -> Adjust Size and check the dpi value. If it isn't 72, correct it but DO NOT change the pixel dimensions. Just the dpi value.

Comment: hey ole..... it worked for me man.... Thanku so much... i was scratching my head dude this problem..... Thanku sooo much... im giving u a vote up..... Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are your image files saved with 72 dpi? I have seen Interface Builder occasionally having problems with files that do not have 72 dpi (even though this value is almost meaningless for pixel-based display).

To check, open the images in Preview.app, choose Tools -> Adjust Size and check the dpi value. If it isn't 72, correct it but DO NOT change the pixel dimensions. Just the dpi value.